# Connection time out is not working in HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient 4.3.6 in my java code for POST HTTP call. I am getting 504 Gateway timeout error in post call, so I have set connection timeout using below 2 approaches:

1--------

```
RequestConfig requestConfig =
RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(180 * 1000).build();
final HttpClient httpClient = 
          HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

final HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(utility.getUrl());
```

2---------

```
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

final HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(utility.getUrl());

RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.DEFAULT;

RequestConfig requestConfig =
            RequestConfig
                .copy(rc)
                .setSocketTimeout(180 * 1000)
                .setConnectTimeout(180 * 1000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(180 * 1000)
                .build();
postRequest.setConfig(requestConfig);
```

After even trying above approach with timeout of 3 minute, I am getting 504 timeout if POST response gets more than 1 minute. It is not waiting till 3 minute. please tell if I am doing wrong here.

Comment: if you get status code 504 - then the problem definitly not on client side

Comment: Quite so. If the client got *anything* there is *no* problem with the client whatsoever, and if the client got `504 Gateway timeout` the overwhelming preseumtpion is that the problem is at the gateway or upstream.

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @Boris if you are getting [504](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504) then this is definitely not client-side and the timeout must be coming from Server. All Webserver has default timeout configuration. For example check [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#:%7E:text=Use%20a%20value%20of%20%2D1,request%20body%20(if%20any).), which sets default timeout to 60 seconds. I think you should check timeout configuration of webserver which you are calling.

Comment: For some reason, someone didn't like my answer :-(